# Enable an epel repo via script?

Tags: regex, sed, yum

I'm installing the Epel repo via a shell script, the repo comes by default disabled, I would like to enable it so the script can install further packages.

The following install the Epel repo:

```
yum install -y epel-release
```

This will create  /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo, which contains:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-debug-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/SRPMS
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-source-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
gpgcheck=1
```

Now, I want to enable only the first repo '[epel]. I tried with sed but so far only managed to enable all of them (I'm a sed beginner):

```
sh-3.2$ sed 's,enabled=0,enabled=1,g;' ./epel.repo
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-debug-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/SRPMS
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-source-5&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
gpgcheck=1
```

This version of the command will not change anything:

```
sed 's,\(\[epel\].*\)enabled=0,\1enabled=1,;' ./epel.repo
```

What is the regex that will work for me? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed(1)` doesn't edit the file in place, it sends the edits to its output. To edit in-place you need to give the `-i` (or `--in-place`) flag. Also, what you are doing is to edit lines that contain `[epel].*enabled`, which you just won't find. You want to limit the replacement to the section starting `[epel]`, which ends with the next `[`:

```
sed -i -e '/\[epel\]/,/^\[/s/enabled=0/enabled=1/' ./epel.repo
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually knew it wasn't editing in place, I just copy pasted my test but was planning to use an output redirect in the final version. The -i flag is handy. It took some time to understand what your example was doing, for those trying the same in the future, this page should make the solution clear: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29

Comment: @CleberGoncalves, be careful! The shell manages redirections (`>`, etc) *before* doing the job, and in particular e.g. `sed -e 's/a/b/g' my-file > my-file` will clobber `my-file` *before* calling `sed(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your question defines any specific parameters around command line tools, but I find the `yum-config-manager` command useful:

`yum-config-manager --enable epel`

Example:

```
> cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo | grep '\[.*\]\|enabled.*'
[epel]
enabled=0
[epel-debuginfo]
enabled=0
[epel-source]
enabled=0
> yum-config-manager --enable epel
[ ... REMOVE LONG OUTPUT ... ]
> cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo | grep '\[.*\]\|enabled.*'
[epel]
enabled=1
[epel-debuginfo]
enabled=0
[epel-source]
enabled=0
> yum-config-manager --disable epel
[ ... REMOVE LONG OUTPUT ... ]
> cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo | grep '\[.*\]\|enabled.*'
[epel]
enabled=0
[epel-debuginfo]
enabled=0
[epel-source]
enabled=0
```